# How do I write an async wrapper around a third party IO library in C#

Tags: c#, .net, io, async-await

I need to use a library that provides access to its own database. Unfortunately, all methods are classic synchronous. I'd prefer to have `async` methods to offload the IO load like we already have for say SQL Server.

I understand this is a very generic question without much concrete information. Are there any means to move to that point or is it just too bad?

Examples and/or links would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unless you have access to the source, you can't wrap it yourself an make it truly asynchronous. Unless it already exposes some async API's for you, that will be a problem.

Comment: You'll need some form of async calls in this 3rd party library. Someting like BeginRead() / EndRead(). With such pairs it is possible to write an async / awaitable Wrapper.

Comment: [Relevant post on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

If there's some form of asynchronous API in the library you are using you can use it to manufacture `async` API with `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. It can be `BeginX`/`EndX`, `DoX` with a `XCompleted` event or any other form.

If nothing like that exists, you simply **can't create truly asynchronous overloads**. You can offload these synchronous calls to a `ThreadPool` thread using `Task.Run` but that would only help with responsiveness and not with performance in any way.

Comment: If its `BeginX/EndX` you can use the `FromAsync` factory method instead of `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RicoSuter sure... It was a generalization. `FromAsync` uses the same Task API `TaskCompletionSource` uses.